# How to install modules and recompile php with jetty

Tags: php, apache, gd, jpgraph, mbstring

PHP app is served with Jetty.

I need to add mbstring and PHP GD. This would be fairly straightforward, How can I achieve this when jetty is serving php.

--- UPDATE---

I managed to install mb-string and gd and I can see them in the list of modules when i run `php -m` but I still get this error in my app:

`This PHP installation is not configured with the GD library. Please recompile PHP with GD support to run JpGraph. (Neither function imagetypes() nor imagecreatefromstring() does exist)`

AND

`mPDF requires mb_string functions. Ensure that PHP is compiled with php_mbstring.dll enabled.`

Result of `php -m`:

```
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
zip
zlib
```

Host OS: CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

UPDATE 2:

Upon running phpinfo(); I discovered the apache is indeed installed ( although I couldnt find a apache2 directory in `/etc`.

`Server API Apache 2.0 Handler`

Im still not sure how to `re-compile` php to activate the modules.

More info:

`Loaded Configuration File  /etc/php.ini`

```
Configure Command   './configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--without-mysql' '--without-gd' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC' '--disable-pdo' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter' '--without-sqlite3' '--disable-phar' '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-json' '--without-pspell' '--disable-wddx' '--without-curl' '--disable-posix' '--disable-sysvmsg' '--disable-sysvshm' '--disable-sysvsem'
```

Apache Environment:

`GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1`

Comment: This might be a serverfault question. However, depending on your OS there should be packages available for each of the modules.

Comment: @jedifans update with host OS info

Comment: How does jetty run php? Is it via fastcgi or php-fpm? If you have a php file with `<?php phpinfo();` it should help inform you and us.

Comment: @jedifans which part of the phpinfo() page should I post here?

Comment: @jedifans Jetty has FastCGI support, quite a few wordpress instances out there now using Jetty with HTTP/2 and push support.

Comment: Oh right. I think I would choose nginx personally but nice to know about alternatives! @ImpendingDoom, was trying to establish which ini files are used as the cli uses different ones sometimes.